# Set one of the angular HTTP data variables to a boolean

Tags: angularjs, post

Edit: Is this possibly an issue with the backend API? The data requests sent over $.param are always strings, correct? So they need to parse that stuff on their backend?

I am currently trying to send a post request to an API to register a user. One of the requirements is to accept terms and conditions and an age requirement, which it expects a boolean.

I believe the issue might be that the $http request is sending a STRING and not a boolean to the API backend and so it's rejecting it. How would I send a boolean through $http?

```
    var apiCall = {
      method: 'POST',
      url: 'API_URL',
      data: $.param({
        'user[email]': username,
        'user[password]': password,
        'user[password_confirmation]':password,
        'profile[age_acceptance]': ageAcceptance,
        'profile[terms_acceptance]': termsAcceptance
      }),
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/vnd.softswiss.v1+json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
      },
      transformRequest: function(data, headersGetter, status) {
        console.log(data);
        console.log(headersGetter(data));
      }
    }
```

Comment: Try using a console.log statement (or dev tools debugger) to see what `typeof termsAcceptance` returns. Then you'll know for sure whether it's an issue with types.

Comment: Already done. the values being passed into $.param are booleans -- but when I log the transform request it's just one big string (which may be normal, but I'm just trying to figure out why I'm getting rejected from the API).

Comment: Does your API accept `'Content-Type': 'application/json'` instead of `x-www-form-urlencoded`?

Comment: Instead of using the jQuery param encoder, use the [$httpParamSerializer service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$httpParamSerializer)  The [DEMO on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hensb6wd/)

Comment: This appears to have the same functionality as $.param, what is the advantage? (Didn't fix the issue by the by, just curious).

Comment: The headers are only:

` Accept: application/vnd.softswiss.v1+json
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

For this API call.

Answer (score 0):

```
var dataToPost = JSON.stringify( {
    'user[email]': username,
    'user[password]': password,
    'user[password_confirmation]':password,
    'profile[age_acceptance]': ageAcceptance,
    'profile[terms_acceptance]': termsAcceptance
  });

  data: dataToPost,
  headers: {.......,
   .....
```

you have to stringy your parameters.

```
JSON.stringify(params)
```

Comment: Modified the API call like this:

the error message now says emails are invalid. Not sure this is the correct solution. 
          data: $.param({
            'user[email]': JSON.stringify(username),
            'user[password]': JSON.stringify(password),
            'user[password_confirmation]': JSON.stringify(password),
            'profile[age_acceptance]': JSON.stringify(ageAcceptance),
            'profile[terms_acceptance]': JSON.stringify(termsAcceptance)
          }),

Comment: So, the api expects a response like this:

"user%5Bemail%5D=a%40b.x&user%5Bpassword%5D=test1234&user%5Bpassword_confirmation%5D=test1234&profile%5Bage_acceptance%5D=true&profile%5Bterms_acceptance%5D=true"

When I do it your way, I get it like this:

"{"user[email]":"a@b.c","user[password]":"test1234","user[password_confirmation]":"test1234","profile[age_acceptance]":true,"profile[terms_acceptance]":true}"

I think I can't use JSON.stringify because the API is expecting a big string...

But if it wants a boolean value, I'm not sure $.param sends anything but a string. Hmm.